# Is it possible to access the assets folder from the Android system?

Tags: android, root, in-app-billing

Is it possible to get access to the files in an apps assets folder from the outside Android system? if you install for an instance Clash of Clans, can you use a root explorer to get into CoC's assets folder(if it has one of course)? I am trying to get the perfect protection for the Android base64 code and as generated files are accessible from the system with root, it is either assets folder, or an SQL database(if that is safe)

Answer (score 0):

> can you use a root explorer to get into CoC's assets folder(if it has one of course)?

`assets/` is a folder on your development machine. It is a set of files packaged in the APK file. These are universally accessible, without root.

Comment: What I mean is can the user get access to it and see the files inside

Comment: @TheRealPolarbear: Yes, if the user copies the APK off of the device. Probably there are apps that allow browsing of assets even on the device, though I do not know of any.

Comment: is it possible to alter the data of the files inside the assets folder?

Comment: @TheRealPolarbear: Not without root. Even then, it would invalidate the digital signature of the APK file, though I do not know if that has any ramifications for already-installed apps.